# Como lidar com informações na qual não se tem fontes confiáveis mas são as únicas disponíveis?

Tags: discussion, answers

Vi [essa pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/250/qual-a-origem-e-o-significado-do-%c3%89-pique-%c3%a9-hora-ra-tim-bum) sobre a origem do Ratimbum dos aniversários, e ia responder, mas as informações que sei sobre isso não têm em nenhum site confiável, ou melhor, nem citam o assunto.
Têm alguns sites, mas são apenas parcialmente confiáveis, e não se tem a garantia de que os mesmos não foram influenciados por outros sites.

Então eu queria saber se eu respondo e deixo claro de que é uma teoria e que nada está definitivamente comprovado, ou não respondo.

Comment: Acho que devias responder deixando claro que é uma teoria. "Eu acho" ou "alguém disse". Acho que no caso deste site deveriam sempre existir fontes para darmos valor a nossa resposta. Mas a verdade é que é complicado arranjar fontes confiáveis para a maioria das perguntas. Os utilizadores do site depois vão dar upvote ou downvote conforme acharem a sua informação verídica ou não. Mas realmente é uma questão pertinente.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Diferente dos Stack Overflows, as perguntas no PL não vêm de pessoas com *problemas* que devem ser *resolvidos*. É uma distinção que tem bastante impacto, porque significa que as respostas podem ser testadas, e não dependem de referências para serem consideradas corretas. Se funciona, funciona e ponto.

O PL é um site mais teórico, onde a maioria das perguntas são sobre *dúvidas* (não necessariamente *problemas*). Elas não buscam uma solução, mas sim uma resposta que seja adequada e válida. Não é possível testar para saber se a resposta para os 4 tipos de "porque" funciona.

Respostas aqui precisam ter algum tipo de validação. Uma referência externa confiável é uma validação explícita. Por outro lado, muitos votos em uma resposta funcionam como uma validação *implícita* da veracidade da resposta. Mas isso só funciona se tivermos uma comunidade capaz de identificar o que são boas respostas.

Então, referências externas não são absolutamente necessárias. São desejáveis, mas não devem ser exigidas. O que é, sim, necessário, é uma comunidade de pessoas com conhecimento sobre a área, capazes de prover e identificar boas respostas, mesmo sem necessidade de fontes externas.

Comment: Numa fase inicial em que não temos uma comunidade ideal para identificar inequivocamente boas e más respostas, referências são sempre bem vindas. Não concorda?

Comment: @E_net4 sim, desculpe se não ficou claro na resposta. Só acho que há uma distinção entre algo ser *bem-vindo* e ser *requerido*. Acho que nenhuma resposta deve receber downvotes, ou ser apagada, apenas por não ter um link de referência, mas são um indicativo bem evidente de respostas de qualidade